# Create keyboard shortcuts for menu bar items that don't have shortcuts?

Tags: macos, appletv, airplay

How can I create a keyboard shortcut for something that doesn't have a keyboard shortcut? Example, I use Airparrot to mirror my iMac to my Apple TV. I'd like to assign a keyboard shortcut to the airparrot menu selection that enables display mirroring to my TV. That way I can just use a remote on my iphone while I'm sitting on my couch to mirror my iMac remotely, without having to go upstairs to the computer and back down. Any ideas?

To me airplay mirroring is pointless if you can't enable it remotely.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

1. Go to **System Preferences / Keyboard / Keyboard Shortcuts / Applications**.
2. Click the **+** button.
3. Choose the Application you want to assign the shortcut to, from the drop-down list.
4. On the *menu title* field add **the exact name** of the menu bar item.
5. Pick your keyboard shortcut and click **Add**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a shortcut is to open Automator and record the action that you want and save it as a service. Then go to that service in service preferences and establish your preferred keyboard shortcut.