# Disabling Command + Arrow scrolling

Tags: keyboard, macos

When I press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> on OS X 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion), it scrolls all the way to the top or the bottom of a window.

The problem is, in some programs, this results in crazy uncontrollable scrolling behavior, because for whatever reason the program doesn't signal to the OS that it's hit the end of its scrolling. It's driving me nuts.

Is there any way to turn off this behavior? I've searched System Preferences > Keyboard settings to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intention is to *globally* override this behaviour, this will do the trick:

Create a file called `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` and write on it the following:

```
    {
      "@\UF700" = "noop:";
      "@\UF701" = "noop:";
    }
```

`@\UF700` is the Unicode value for <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> while
`@\UF701` is for <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>.

Save it and place it under `~/Library/KeyBindings/`. If the folder doesn't exist, just create it.

A **different** approach would be to override this *shortcuts* on each of the Applications you're having troubles with, assigning the *problematic* shortcuts to the Application's function you usually don't use, for instance.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot. Could you elaborate a bit on your "different" approach — how would I override this in an application-specific way?

Comment: @nucleon [Here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72571/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-menu-bar-items-that-dont-have-shortcuts/72739#72739) :)